# Add Noise to Background for Voice Separation

Tags: python, nlp, voice, generative-adversarial-network

I want to implement a voice separation project. Now, I got a voice dataset with no background noise and a dataset about noise, such as engine sound , horn sound. How can I add(I don't know is this action called "add") this noise to the clean data? The noise is not as long as the clean voice, so do I need to repeat the noise to make them the same length? Or there is a method or a module can do this?

[image: the image about clean, noise, and mixed voice]

Comment: The link is the image show what I want to do, I don't know why it can show on the question?

Comment: I fixed it for you :)